# What is "this" in Form correspond in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

The "this" that we use in Form application. What does it correspond to in WPF? Is it MainWindow? I am using a library that is build around Form application and there are alot of "this" and I don't know how to convert the "this" in WPF

Comment: Inside a class with for example a field named `_myVariable`
  `this._myVariable.SomeMethod()` is the same as `_myVariable.Somemethod()` and comes in place of adding the class name infront of a variable or method when calling from a different class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, [`this`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is always a reference to the current instance of the class in which it is used.

In fact, to quote from MSDN:

> The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class.
>
> The following are common uses of this:
>
> - To qualify members hidden by similar names
> - To pass an object as a parameter to other methods
> - To declare indexers

Examples can be found following the link above.

There is an exception to this rule when working with [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), however, where `this` is a modifier to the type of object by which the extension method is to be exposed.

Comment: @KMC, what exactly is *"it doesn't work"*? **this** is not specific to WinForms or WPF, it is the same across both, it is a **language** feature.

Comment: @KMC: You misunderstand, I didn't say that would work, and it shouldn't work. In fact, without some example code, I'm inclined to say that use of `this` may not even be a problem in porting of your code.

Comment: @KMC Shouldn't have to `this` has nothing to do with Forms but with `C#` regardless of the type of project.

Answer (score 1):

this is always the class that it is in

think of it as `this is in this class`